# How do I redirect https://www.hhl.com/articlename.html?a=b to https://www.hhl.com/articlename/?a=b

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just converted a website over to a new implementation. The old site had URLs that ended in .html; now I'm using the "normal" WordPress way in which they look like a directory. How do I redirect:

```
      https://www.hhl.com/articlename.html?a=b 
...to https://www.hhl.com/articlename/?a=b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I assume that roughly is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?articlename\.html$ /articlename/ [R=301,QSA]
```

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

UPDATE: 
In the comments you explained that the "articlename" portion of the URL is dynamic, that was not mentioned in the original question. Here is an updated version taking that into account:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9_-])\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm using a hosting provider (SiteGround), so it has to be in .htaccess.

Comment: What about the ?a=b part?

Comment: And there are 5,000 articles of this type, it needs to capture the "articlename" from original URL rather than specifying it hard-coded.

Comment: So would this be closer: RewriteRule ^([^\?]+)\.html(.*)$ $1/$2 [R301,QSA]

Comment: I added a modified version taking into accout that the articlename is dynamic. The existing HTTP GET arguments (`?a=b`) are automatically preserved by the `QSA` flag.